# Copy Paste Files with delay

Tags: batch-file, copy-paste

I have a script which copy files and paste. I just want to have a delay which paste files in order.
Paste first file - 10 sec wait - Paste second file - 10 sec delay - Paste third file -...

This is my script which copy all files

```
set source=C:\Users\kco2bu\Desktop\Deneme\Copy
set destination=C:\Users\kco2bu\Desktop\Deneme\Paste
xcopy %source% %destination% /y
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

copy each file on it's own:

```
set "source=C:\Users\kco2bu\Desktop\Deneme\Copy"
set "destination=C:\Users\kco2bu\Desktop\Deneme\Paste"
for %%a in ("%source%\*") do (
  xcopy "%%~fa" "%destination%" /y
  timeout -t 10 >nul
)
```

Comment: `timeout` doesn't work always. For example, Jenkins and some other build servers won't allow the timeout command. In this case, you can replace it with `ping localhost -n 11`. Yes, 11 is correct. It has to be 1 more than the number of seconds you want to wait.

Comment: Yes, @MichaelS, `timeout` can fail; it does when input redirection is used, for example...