# Copy subdirectories one at a time with a pause

Tags: batch-file, move, subdirectory

I have a folder tree with several subdirectories within subdirectories. I am looking for a batch script to move one bottom level subdirectory, wait 10 minutes and move the next, wait 10 minutes and so on. Alternatively I could move one file, wait a minute, then move the next and so on, as long is it replicates the directory structure.

I have been able to COPY files from a folder with a delay between each file using instructions found here: [Copy Paste Files with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44238628/copy-paste-files-with-delay)

However I want to MOVE files and include subdirectories.

The reason behind this request is that I am moving a large amount of media (video specifically) and it needs to be checked into a database once it lands in the scanned location. Because the database is in use, dumping the entire contents of the top level folder will overload the system. At the moment I am manually moving one bottom level folder at a time and it is taking up way too much of my time.

Thanks!

Comment: The 'instructions' you've linked, uses `xcopy.exe`, which you could replace with `robocopy.exe`. If you open a Command Prompt window, type `robocopy /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, you should note within the output, that it can move files and directories, not just copy them. All you should need to do is choose the most appropriate options for your specific needs, and make the replacement.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I use robocopy a lot but simply replacing xcopy with robocopy in those 'instructions' did not work.

Comment: You cannot simply replace them, you need to change the options to those you require too. I would advise that you provide your attempts at using RoboCopy, and along side each, explain what specific issue is exhibited with each, and what measures you've taken yourself to address them. Currently only you have that information, so unless you tell us what it is, and properly explain the task, we'd have to guess, and that is not what we do on a technical site.